# Get data points from a histogram in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I made a histogram of the 'cdf' (cumulative distribution) of a function. The histogram is basically No. of counts vs. luminosity. Now, how do I extract data points from a histogram? I need actual values of Luminosities.
I am using Matplotlib in Python, and any online book, example, tutorial etc is not helping.

```
l= [ss.gammainccinv(aa+1, u[i]) for i in a] #is the cdf function
plt.hist(l, 50, histtype= 'step', align='mid') #is the histogram
plt.show()
```

I am not sure if I should align the bins to the edges or the mid point, but all I need is a list of l's.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 34):

You've already got a list of `l`s, so I'm not sure what you mean by that last statement, so maybe I've misinterpreted the question.

To get the values from a histogram, `plt.hist` returns them, so all you have to do is save them.

If you don't save them, the interpreter just prints the output:

```
In [34]: x = np.random.rand(100)

In [35]: plt.hist(x)
Out[35]: 
(array([ 11.,   9.,  10.,   6.,   8.,   8.,  10.,  10.,  11.,  17.]),
 array([ 0.00158591,  0.100731  ,  0.19987608,  0.29902116,  0.39816624,
        0.49731133,  0.59645641,  0.69560149,  0.79474657,  0.89389165,
        0.99303674]),
 <a list of 10 Patch objects>)
```

So, to save them, do:

```
counts, bins, bars = plt.hist(x)
```

Comment: yes, all I needed to do was "print l" instead of "print l[i]". That only gave the first number from the array. Or a number. Learning from the silly mistakes. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also retrieve info from an already plotted histogram. For example:

```
x = np.random.rand(100)
plt.hist(x)
```

[image]

```
ax = plt.gca() # get axis handle
```

You can access to each individual bar using `patches`. Then `.get_xy()` will give you the x-y coordiate of a single bar (lower left corner), `.get_width()` will give width of the bar, and `.get_height()` will give the height of the bar (which is probably what you want).

```
p = ax.patches  # There are 10 patches
p[0].get_xy()
>> (0.011714084185001972, 0.0)
p[0].get_width()
>> 0.09871329223828645
p[0].get_height()
>> 8.0
```

So to retrieve all the heights:

```
heights = [patch.get_height() for patch in p]
```

And to reproduce the histogram:

```
plt.bar(range(len(heights)), heights)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the assignments to bins, You can do it in the following way as explained here [Which elements of list go into which histogram bins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542749/which-elements-of-list-go-into-which-histogram-bins)

```
nbins=7
# Some example data
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10) 
B = np.random.rand(10)

counts, binEdges=np.histogram(A,bins=nbins)
>>> binEdges, np.digitize(A, binEdges)
array([ 0.        ,  1.28571429,  2.57142857,  3.85714286,  5.14285714,
    6.42857143,  7.71428571,  9.        ])
```