# Which elements of list go into which histogram bins?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I'm trying to make a scaled scatter plot from a histogram. The scatter plot is fairly straight-forward, make the histogram, find bin centers, scatter plot.

```
nbins=7
# Some example data
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, 100) 
B = np.random.rand(100)

counts, binEdges=np.histogram(A,bins=nbins)
bincenters = 0.5*(binEdges[1:]+binEdges[:-1])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(bincenters,counts,c='k', marker='.')
ax_setup(ax, 'X', 'Y')
plt.show()
```

but I want each element of `A` to only contribute a scaled value to it's bin, that scaled value is stored in `B`. (i.e. instead of each bin being the count of elements from `A` for that bin, I want each bin to be the sum of corresponding values from `B`)

To do this I tried creating a list `C` (same length as `A`, and `B`) that had the bin number allocation for each element of `A`, then summing all of the values from `B` that go into the same bin. I thought `numpy.searchsorted()` is what I needed e.g.,

```
C = bincenters.searchsorted(A, 'right')
```

but this doesn't get the allocation right, and doesn't seem to return the correct number of bins.

So, how do I create a list that tells me which histogram bin each element of my data goes into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write

> but I want each element of A to only contribute a scaled value to it's bin, that scaled value is stored in B. (i.e. instead of each bin being the count of elements from A for that bin, I want each bin to be the sum of corresponding values from B)

IIUC, this functionality is already supported in [`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) via the `weights` parameter:

> An array of weights, of the same shape as a. Each value in a only contributes its associated weight towards the bin count (instead of 1). If normed is True, the weights are normalized, so that the integral of the density over the range remains 1.

So, for your case, it would just be

```
counts, binEdges=np.histogram(A, bins=nbins, weights=B)
```

---

Another point: if your intent is to plot the histogram, note that you can directly use `matplotlib.pyplot`'s utility functions for this (which take `weights` as well):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.hist(A, bins=nbins, weights=B);
```

[image]

---

Finally, if you're intent on getting the assignments to bins, then that's exactly what [`numpy.digitize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) does:

```
nbins=7
# Some example data
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10) 
B = np.random.rand(10)

counts, binEdges=np.histogram(A,bins=nbins)
>>> binEdges, np.digitize(A, binEdges)
array([ 0.        ,  1.28571429,  2.57142857,  3.85714286,  5.14285714,
    6.42857143,  7.71428571,  9.        ])
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! This looks like it does the trick of scaling the values as required (very simply too). More of a curiosity I guess then, any idea how I would return the list of bin allocations? It might come in handy at some point.

Comment: Thanks Ami, this is perfect.