# extract data points from a histogram in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use matplotlib to create histograms from extracting data points from textfiles. The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = np.loadtxt('file1.txt')
data2 = np.loadtxt('file2.txt')
x = np.transpose(data1)[1]
y = np.transpose(data2)[1]

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5, label='electrons', 
edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.7, range=[0, 450])
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(y, num_bins, facecolor='magenta', alpha=0.5, label='pions', 
edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.7, range=[0, 450])

plt.show()
```

So far this went well and i got a histogram created. However, my next step is to use the clip() function so that i can define a certain range for my values to be displayed and the outliers are mapped into the first (values which are below the minimum threshold) and the last bin (values which are above the maximum threshold). I have changed the code to:

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(np.clip(x, 8, 400), num_bins, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5, 
label='electrons', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.7, range=[8, 400])
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(np.clip(y, 8, 400), num_bins, facecolor='magenta', alpha=0.5, 
label='pions', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.7, range=[8, 400])
```

The plots are also created correctly here. Now my problem: I want to get the data points from this newly created plot since the data has been changed now and want to write these data points as columns to a text file. How can I do that?

Comment: did you check `bins` or `patches` ? Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128898/get-data-points-from-a-histogram-in-python

Comment: What data points are you talking about "I want to get the data points from this newly created plot (...) want to write these data points as columns to a text file". Do you want to save the height of the bars (which are in the variable `n`) or the clipped data (which are returned by `np.clip()`)?

Comment: Check out my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65739764/11965147