# How to get bins position from df.hist not np.hist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130206/11748994) that we can find bins using `plt.hist` function or using [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html). However, I want to get the bins from `df.hist`. How is it possible?

**Note:**

I do not want to get my data from each column and then pass it to `plt.hist` or `np.histogram` like the following:

```
index = pd.date_range('7-22-2022', '7-22-2023', freq='min')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index)), index=index)
c, bins, bar = plt.hist(df.values, bins=50)
c, bins = np.histogram(df.values, bins=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that you can't do this.  [`df.hist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) doesn't have any options for specifying outputs aside from the plotting axes themselves.

However, by default **plotting with pandas is plotting with matplotlib** - pandas just provides a different API.  Note that if you compare the `bins` returned by `plt.hist` or `np.histogram` in your example, you get identical arrays.  Doing `df.hist(bins=50)` should also give you the same bins.

Just to be thorough, I can say if you look at the source code and follow the `bins` parameter starting here [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.3/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L116-L243) (which is linked from the docs for `df.hist()`), you eventually get to [this line](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e8093ba372f9adfe79439d90fe74b0b5b6dea9d6/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/hist.py#L326) which calls `ax.hist()` (the `ax` being a matplotlib Axes object).  And if you look at the implementation of [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.5.2/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L6339-L6799), you will see it relies on `np.histogram`.  Thus, my impression **they all reduce to using `np.histogram`**.  It's a little hard to trace through these large libraries, however, so perhaps I have missed something.

You say you do not want to get the bins from `np.histogram` for each column - maybe if you could clarify why that is an issue, someone else could provide a more tailored solution.  But I imagine it will involve using `np.histogram` to calculate the bins, because that is what pandas is doing.

---

The only other way I can think of to get the bin edges out of `df.hist()` is to access the bar objects in the plot it creates:

```
# plot
nbins = 50
bar = df.hist(bins=nbins)

# create container for edges
bin_edges = np.zeros(nbins + 1)

# access the bar objects from the ax
ax = bar[0, 0]
patches = ax.patches

# collect the left sides using patch.get_x()
# for the last right edge, add the width
bin_edges[:nbins] = [p.get_x() for p in patches]
bin_edges[-1] = patches[-1].get_x() + patches[-1].get_width()
```

With `bin_edges` being the thing you are requesting:

```
>>> bin_edges
array([-4.53401407, -4.34364948, -4.1532849 , -3.96292032, -3.77255574,
       -3.58219116, -3.39182657, -3.20146199, -3.01109741, -2.82073283,
       -2.63036825, -2.44000366, -2.24963908, -2.0592745 , -1.86890992,
       -1.67854534, -1.48818075, -1.29781617, -1.10745159, -0.91708701,
       -0.72672243, -0.53635784, -0.34599326, -0.15562868,  0.0347359 ,
        0.22510048,  0.41546507,  0.60582965,  0.79619423,  0.98655881,
        1.17692339,  1.36728798,  1.55765256,  1.74801714,  1.93838172,
        2.1287463 ,  2.31911089,  2.50947547,  2.69984005,  2.89020463,
        3.08056921,  3.2709338 ,  3.46129838,  3.65166296,  3.84202754,
        4.03239212,  4.22275671,  4.41312129,  4.60348587,  4.79385045,
        4.98421503])
```

However, note the difference between `bin_edges` and the `bins` you computed with `np.histogram` is infinitesimal (presumably due to some floating point inaccuracy or rounding error):

```
>>> bin_edges - bins
[ 0.00000000e+00 -8.88178420e-16  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  4.44089210e-16  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  4.44089210e-16  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  4.44089210e-16
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  2.22044605e-16
  2.22044605e-16  0.00000000e+00  2.22044605e-16  0.00000000e+00
  2.22044605e-16  2.22044605e-16  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
```

I'd say using `np.histogram` is more efficient and cleaner for arriving at the same (almost) result.

---

The above is based on the assumption you are not using a different plotting backend for pandas.   The binning implementation could be different for other plotting libraries.